# Pyparsing: how to match parentheses around comma_separated_list

Tags: python, pyparsing

I cannot figure out how to combine expressions with the [comma_separated_list](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html#pyparsing.pyparsing_common.comma_separated_list) in order to match a list in parentheses. The following does not work, because the csv expression eats up the last parenthesis:

```
import pyparsing as pp

rule = "{" + pp.common.comma_separated_list + "}"
rule.parse_string("{something}")

# >>> ParseException: Expected '}', found end of text
```

The values in the list can contain parentheses as well so the rule must match only the outer ones. I guess [1:-1] solves it, but it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: The `}` is seen as part of `something`. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/141980203504a1b58425d1770dc2d99da83d3252/pyparsing/common.py#L351), especially [here](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/141980203504a1b58425d1770dc2d99da83d3252/pyparsing/common.py#L343), the grammar expects a line end to terminate the list. You should copy the relevant parts from source and edit them to make your own variant.

Answer (score 1):

you need to quote the string as below:

```
import pyparsing as pp

rule = "{" + pp.common.comma_separated_list + "}"
result = rule.parse_string("{\"something\",\"anything\"}")
print(result)
```

Comment: I think this should be possible without altering the string inside.

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing's `comma_separated_list` is a convenience helper for common cases of such lists, but it hard codes what it expects to see as list elements. Also, this comment of yours:

> The values in the list can contain parentheses as well

tells me that you actually need a recursive grammar, to parse {}'s within {}'s.

So rather than use the `comma_separated_list` helper (or its similar helper `nested_expr`), I'll walk through defining this expression in steps. (We *will* use `delimited_list`, since it allows us to define an expression for the elements of the list.)

One of the first steps I take when writing a new grammar is to define constants for the punctuation that will be parsed. Generally, punctuation is significant at parse time, but can usually be dropped from the actual parsed results.

```
import pyparsing as pp

LBRACE, RBRACE = map(pp.Suppress, "{}")
# in pyparsing 3.1.0, you will be able to write this as
# LBRACE, RBRACE = Suppress.using_each("{}")
```

Since `rule` will be recursive, we'll start by defining it as a pyparsing `Forward`. That is, we are *forward-declaring* an expression, whose content we will define later. This allows us to use `rule` as part of its own definition. (I'm also going to call `set_name` on most of these expressions, so that we can generate some nice railroad diagrams.)

```
rule = pp.Forward().set_name("rule")
```

The words that will be elements of the rule will be any printable (i.e., non-space) character, excluding the "{", "}", and "," characters that we need for enclosing rules and delimiting the lists.

```
wd_chars = pp.printables
wd =  pp.Word(wd_chars, exclude_chars='{},').set_name("word")
```

To use `delimited_list` with custom content, we need a pyparsing expression for what the items in the list could be. So far, they will either be `wd` expressions or `rule` expressions.

```
content = wd | rule
```

So now we are ready to define what a `rule` is. We can't use a normal "=" operator, since that would replace the `rule` we used to define `content`. Instead we use the "<<=" operator, as a way of "injecting" the grammar for the existing `rule` expression:

```
rule <<= pp.Group(LBRACE + pp.delimited_list(content) + RBRACE)
```

An easy way to test your parser is to use `run_tests`. `run_tests` echoes the input test string, and then lists out the parsed items, or the raised `ParseException`. In fact, if you are following Test-Driven Development, you can start by writing the test code as:

```
rule.run_tests("""
    a simple test
    a slightly more complicated test
    ... etc. ...
""")
```

and then keep adding new tests as you are about to add a new aspect of the parser.

`run_tests` also accepts comments, and so you can label your tests as you define new test strings.  Here are some tests in increasing order of complexity:

```
rule.run_tests("""
    # a rule with just one item
    {something}

    # a rule with multiple items
    {thing1, thing2}

    # a rule containing a simple embedded rule
    {thing1, {thing2a}, thing3}
    
    # a rule containing a rule with multiple items
    {thing1, {thing2a, thing2b}, thing3}
    
    # an empty rule
    {}
""", full_dump=False)
```

Which prints:

```
# a rule with just one item
{something}
[['something']]

# a rule with multiple items
{thing1, thing2}
[['thing1', 'thing2']]

# a rule containing a simple embedded rule
{thing1, {thing2a}, thing3}
[['thing1', ['thing2a'], 'thing3']]

# a rule containing a rule with multiple items
{thing1, {thing2a, thing2b}, thing3}
[['thing1', ['thing2a', 'thing2b'], 'thing3']]

# an empty rule
{}
{}
 ^
ParseException: Expected rule, found '}'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
FAIL: Expected rule, found '}'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
```

Interesting! If an empty rule is not supported, then just remove the last test. But if you want to be able to parse such a rule, then we'll need to modify our parser slightly, to indicate that the list of content items inside the {}'s is optional:

```
rule <<= pp.Group(LBRACE + pp.Opt(pp.delimited_list(content)) + RBRACE)
# in pyparsing 3.1.0, you will be able to write this as
# rule <<= pp.Group(LBRACE + (pp.delimited_list(content) | "") + RBRACE)
```

Here is the railroad diagram pyparsing will create for this parser, with this statement:

```
rule.create_diagram("rule_parser.html")
```

[image: A railroad diagram showing the composition of the rule expression]

Lastly, what do we do if we need to create a rule item that does contain a comma or brace? Or perhaps multiple words? It is not unreasonable to expect that such an item should be enclosed in quotes. Pyparsing includes some built-in expressions, like `dbl_quoted_string` for a string enclosed in `"` characters. If we need that, we can expand the definition of `content`:

```
content = pp.dbl_quoted_string | wd | rule
```

Which modifies the diagram description of `content`:

[image: A railroad diagram showing the modified content expression]

(A question for study by the reader: why does the `dbl_quoted_string` expression have to come before `wd`?)

And add this test to our call to `run_tests`:

```
# a rule with embedded , and brace characters
{thing1, "tricky rule with characters like , { and }", thing2}
```

which gives this added output:

```
# a rule with embedded , and brace characters
{thing1, "tricky rule with characters like , { and }", thing2}
[['thing1', '"tricky rule with characters like , { and }"', 'thing2']]
```

I may have made some incorrect assumptions about what you are trying to do with your parser, but hopefully from this example you can move forward with your own version of a rule parser.

Comment: Thank you for such an awesome and detailed answer. I have learned a lot about pyparsing. However, there is a real use case for the stated problem and that is the deduplication of bibtex records (https://github.com/ondrejsotolar/bib-deduplicator). For good reasons, I absolutely do not want the parser to touch the insides of the outer parentheses, therefore, the problem is not nested. I have tried the bibtexparser lib, which parses the records completely, and it fails on multiple counts with the ACL anthology bibtex file. So, I replaced it with simpler pyparsing code which works.